# How to retrieve AMI platform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

How do I retrieve platform (windows, Linux/Unix) value for an instance/AMI? AWS Console shows the platform value for an AMI.

I have dumped the **dict** property on the AMI object but it does not show the correct platform?

Answer (score 0):

There is an attribute of the `Image` object called `platform`.  This attribute will have a value of `windows` if the image is a Windows image or `None` if it is Linux.  For example:

```
import boto.ec2
c = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
images = c.get_all_images(owners='self')
for image in images:
    if image.platform == 'windows':
        print('Image {} is a Windows Image'.format(image.id))
    else:
        print('Image {} is a Linux Image'.format(image.id))
```

Comment: Getting the exact linux platform is the problem. I was trying to match instances vs bought reservations. Amazon confirmed though that the linux distribution did not matter.