# Getting AMI-Platform from EC2 CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm working on a script that deals with RI coverage on EC2. When I call the API for RIs I get back a list of attributes including one describing the platform the RI was purchased for

- Linux/Unix
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux
- Windows
- Windows with SQL
- ....

I'm trying to match the current inventory to the RIs that have been / will need to be purchased, but unfortunately I can't seem to figure out a call that will give me that info. I've tried ec2 describe-instances, but that only returns a platform as "windows" or null, also trying ec2-describe-images and getting similar results (although the platform attribute in the console will actually show me more information about the underlying OS)

**Is there a way to get the platform of an AMI or an instance so that I can match this to an RI? Or is there some other way to match an instance/AMI to an RI platform type?**

p.s. I saw a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175894/how-to-retrieve-ami-platform) that says it doesn't matter, however idk what "doesn't matter" means?

Comment: See my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41172415/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-platform-and-os-from-the-instances

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to get the platform and OS from the instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41172415/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-platform-and-os-from-the-instances)

Comment: Thanks @helloV, Seen that one already. Don't think its a duplicate though, considering I don't necessarily need the OS specifically, but rather what RI platform type it qualifies for.

Answer (score 0):

Reserved Instances are not directly associated with EC2 Instances. They are a billing method, e.g. if you have a RI that matches one of your EC2 instances (region, type, etc.), then you are billed at the RI price. Dedicated Instances have matching EC2 instances.